# How to change the phpmyadmin database encoding

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database, some of its data is in hebrew, and I see those symbols..

```
×‘×“×™×§×•×ª ×™×“× ×™×•×ª   ×‘×“×™×§×•×ª ×™×“× ×™×•×ª
```

Is there a way to configure the database so I wont see those symbols?!??

Chrome , as opposed to firefox, also displays those weird symbols.. weird squares

Comment: i'm using the 3.4.6 version of phpmyadmin, and in the home page there is a select with the encoding options. Have you seen it?

Comment: `<joke>`"update sometable set badfield=''" would certainly eliminate those characters...`</joke>`

Comment: Could you change your fields encoding to allow it handle the data? Right next to the field name is where it should be. Just a thought as I'm not sure it'd work.

Comment: they are set to utf8_unicode_ci  .. i think the database is set to something else ..i dont know

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a command line:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset_name;
```

Otherwise from phpmyadmin you could export and then import the database while changing the encoding. When you export it, at the end of the file you'll see something like CHARSET=hebrew_general_ci; Just replace it with whatever you need (e.g. CHARSET=utf8 or CHARSET=latin1_general_ci)